# How to install an iOS app programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on pushing an application on to device.
I was able to download the ipa file (also related profile) programmatically.
The next thing that i have to do is to install this downloaded application file programmatically.
I have done a lot of search and found that sandboxing and other iOS limitations wont allow me to install this app.
I need to know is there a way to install iOS apps programmatically (code or scripts) on the device.
Android provides a mechanism to install apps programmatically using Intents.
Want to know if there is anything analogoues or similar to what Android provides in iOS

Comment: For AppStore apps, NO. Jailbroken phones, Maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, at least not from the device. (Caveat: I mean a non-jailbroken device.)

What you *can* do is make an IPA available on a website and download it to a device. This is how enterprise deployment works, and you can use the same trick for *ad hoc* builds.

There's a project on GitHub that automates this: [BetaBuilder](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder).

This probably isn't what you're looking for, but it's the closest that you can currently get as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it programmatically from a Mac with this tool:

https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy

I've used it successfully.