# PhoneGap install downloaded APK or IPA file

Tags: cordova

I'd like to write a simple application that works for both iOS and Android that does the following:

1. query a server for a list of apps (APK and IPA files)
2. show the results to the user
3. let the user select one
4. download the file to the device
5. launch native installer for the file

I think steps 1 to 4 should be trivial, but is it possible to do step 5 from within PhoneGap?
Might window.open work or would I need to write a Plugin to execute native functionality for the install?

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 5 for Android is possible but a prompt to the user cannot be avoided:

[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Step 5 for IOS, as you can imagine, is not possible:

[How to install an iOS app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392143/how-to-install-an-ios-app-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks. I will probably just make a native Android app then.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap/ Cordova is just an HTML wrapper. You can use AJAX or jQuery to fetch the results, either pre-formatted HTML or in JSON format.